ci pipeline building an artifact for a function app contains no functions
I have a function app, I want to deploy functions into that function app
I made a CI and a CD pipeline in azure devops, all of it results in no functions in the function app
this is what my CI yaml looks like
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '*.csproj'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
    projects: '*.csproj'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip"
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildId).zip
    artifactName: 'adofunc'

I believe the problem is the artifact. I have tried to download this artifact and deploy the zip using az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path> after setting SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT to true, also resulted in no functions
I manually set up another function app with functions in there, download the content from portal and compared the zip, they were very differernt
I have tried to use PublishBuildArtifacts@1 instead of PublishPipelineArtifact@1 in the pipeline, was no different, still the same old broken zip, and not having functions


Add a CmdLine@2 task before ArchiveFiles@2. In the task run cd publish_output and dir to check whether your functions are in your publish_output folder. 2. You can also build and publish your project on your local machine using dotnet CLI. Archive publish_output folder and deploy it using Azure CLI. Then you can know whether it's related to your project.


Testing your YAML file, it works fine on my side. I am guessing it's related to your project or function app. Please share screenshots to show your project's folder structure and app settings.

the folder structure is just a folder with the .sln and the function app > the function app folder with the .cs and .csproj, the app settings is a default app settings

is the zip supposed to contain the different .cs? because the reason why I thought the zip is the problem is that there isn't any of the functions. but it has the functionapp.deps.json
functionapp.dll
functionapp.exe
functionapp.pdb
functionapp.json

“is the zip supposed to contain the different .cs” - The zip will not contain the .cs files. There will be a .azurefunctions folder. Inside it, there will be function.deps.json, functionapp.dll, etc.

Based on the current situation, your yaml file is fine. To know whether it's related to your project. please build and publish your project on your local machine using the same dotnet CLI. Archive publish_output folder and deploy it using Azure CLI. If there is the same issue when build and deploy locally, we can confirm there is something to do with your project. And then we can focus on it.

I did dotnet publish -c Release -o publish_output. the contents in publish_output is from what I can see, exactly the same as the artifact the pipeline produces. So yes I also think my ci pipeline is fine. I try to deploy the publish_output.zip using az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path>, this returns a Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ... Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202 and nothing is happening on my function app

The issue is related to your project itself. How did you create your project? Are you following the official doc?

you're right, there is something up with the project. I have recreated everything and it seems to work now. Which is weird because this project had no problems before. It is just now that I am deploying it to another environment it doesn't work. Anyhow, seems like both my ci and cd is fine. Thanks for the pointers.

Hi, @nevermonday, it's great to know creating a new project resolved the issue. To help others may have the similar issue, I add an answer below.

Root Cause & Solution: The question is caused by your project itself. Following the official doc to create a new project resolves the issue.
For any similar issue, you can build and deploy your function app locally to check whether it's caused by your project or the Azure pipeline.
Official docs for your reference:

Zip deployment for Azure Functions
Create your first C# function in Azure using Visual Studio


When creating the artefacts, there's a .azurefunctions hidden folder to be deployed, but you specify your pipeline to include the hidden files (include-hidden-files: true):
- name: Upload artifacts
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
  with:
    name: my-artifacts
    path: |
      .env
      docker-compose.yaml
    include-hidden-files: true

